# Newbie - relation in database

Tags: django

```
class MyBox(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    secret_code = models.CharField(max_length=64, unique=True)
```

How to create relation `MyBox` to `secret_code` (1:n) in Django?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use ForeignKeys, see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#foreignkey.

In your case :

```
class MyBox(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

class SecretCode(models.Model):
  box = models.ForeignKey(MyBox, related_name="secret_codes")
  code = models.CharField(max_length=64, unique=True)
```

You can reverse the relation by simply using :

```
box = MyBox.objects.get(pk=1)
box.secret_codes.all()
```